# Can't add users anymore by using useradd

Tags: useradd

Whenever I do

```
# useradd -N --gid 1003 -s /bin/ksh --uid <some UID starting with 10027> --home /home/<someuser> <someuser>
```

useradd just refuses to add any user and prints instead:

```
useradd: Can't get unique secondary UID range
useradd: can't find subordinate user range
```

And just to tell you, the `/etc/passwd` is 9056 lines long.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have any custom limits on UID range? defined in /etc/login.defs UID_MIN,UID_MAX ?

Comment: No. They are 1000 and 60000 respectively as it came with my distro.

Comment: What OS are you running? are you in a container environment? check for subuid/gid definitions or files /etc/subuid, /etc/subgid

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04. `uname`: `Linux server 3.19.0-28-lowlatency #30~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Tue Sep 1 10:24:39 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: And no I am not. And how do I check that? I opened `/etc/subuid` and the highest value was 600016544.

Comment: what are the values of SUB_UID_MIN, SUB_UID_MAX, SUB_UID_COUNT in /etc/login.defs?

Comment: They are not defined.

Comment: Thanks. Can you paste outputs of /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid files? from the error message, it looks like useradd exhausted the range of sub uid's and it's unable to create new user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30979/discussion-between-tildearrow-and-venkatc).

Comment: "And just to tell you, the /etc/passwd is 9056 lines long.", and you expect that this machine should have thousands of users?  if this is surprising to you then that's likely the key to the whole situation.

Comment: @Theophrastus, what's wrong with having 9056 (or more) users on a system?  not uncommon with, say, a mail server.  or a large corporate or university or govt etc server that uses the organisation's LDAP or AD server for account info.  not all of those users will be logged in or using services on the machine at the same time.

Comment: @cas of course nothing is wrong with it if that meets with the expectation for that machine.  i've got over 23,000 on the box i'm scribbling this on.  yet the way the poster posed it, it sounded like that was an unexpected state; and therefore coming to could certainly prove a key to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [useradd(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/useradd.8.html),
it creates SUB_UID_COUNT secondary uid range reserved for each user

> `SUB_UID_MIN` (number), `SUB_UID_MAX` (number), `SUB_UID_COUNT` (number)
>
>   If
>   `/etc/subuid`
>   exists, the commands
>   `useradd`
>   and
>   `newusers`
>   (unless the user already have subordinate user IDs)
>   allocate
>   `SUB_UID_COUNT`
>   unused user IDs
>   from the range
>   `SUB_UID_MIN`
>   to
>   `SUB_UID_MAX`
>   for each new user.
>
> The default values for `SUB_UID_MIN`, `SUB_UID_MAX`, `SUB_UID_COUNT` are respectively 100000, 600100000 and 10000.

Looks like you reached that default limit and therefore `useradd` is failing.

Answer (score 0):

`useradd` is complaining that it cannot allocate a subordinate UID range for the new user because the allowed UID range is exhausted. 
As you indicated, you have a lot of users in your system,
and the default values configured in `login.defs` can't handle that.

Subordinate UID/GID files are used to set up UID/GID mappings for user namespaces (see [`subuid(5)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/subuid.5.html), [`subgid(5)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/subgid.5.html), [`newuidmap(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/newuidmap.1.html), and [`newgidmap(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/newgidmap.1.html) ).

In my case, I had 10000+ UIDs in my system,
and  `useradd` was failing with exactly the same error. 
I didn't want `useradd` to manage the `subuid` and `subgid` databases
as I don't need to configure any custom ID mappings,
so I've disabled this feature. 
This can be done by removing the `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` files.

For recent versions of shadow utilities (since 4.9 [or so](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/commit/663824ef4ca927aa2b4319b69e0bfa68282ec719)),
setting `SUB_UID_COUNT 0` and `SUB_GID_COUNT 0`
in your `/etc/login.defs` also works. 
See [`login.defs(5)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/login.defs.5.html) for details.